# gwt visualization api labels disappear when displaying multiple charts

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, label

I just want to display several Charts in the same Panel. It doesn't matter which chart types I use (Column, Line, Pie etc). The result is that only the first chart has labels, no matter how many charts I try to display. See this screen shot:

[image]

On the second chart, the x- and y-axis labels are missing as well as the labels for the data sets. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE. Always the same.

Here is the code I use:

```
            VerticalPanel panel=new VerticalPanel();
            final int height = 400;
            final int width = 1200;
            Date d = new Date();

            //message data
            final DataTable msgData = DataTable.create();
            msgData.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "date");
            msgData.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "data one");
            msgData.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "data two");
            msgData.addRows(6);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {

                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                msgData.setValue(i, 0, d);
                msgData.setValue(i, 1, i + 11);
                msgData.setValue(i, 2, i + 12);
            }

            final Options options = Options.create();
            options.setWidth(width);
            options.setHeight(height);
            options.setIsStacked(true);
            options.setTitle("Chart One");

            panel.add(new ColumnChart(msgData, options));

            d = new Date();
            //new data
            final DataTable newData = DataTable.create();
            newData.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "date");
            newData.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "data three");
            newData.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "data four");
            newData.addRows(5);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                newData.setValue(i, 0, d);
                newData.setValue(i, 1, i + 3);
                newData.setValue(i, 2, i + 4);
            }

            final Options options_new = Options.create();
            options_new.setWidth(width);
            options_new.setHeight(height);
            options_new.setIsStacked(true);
            options_new.setTitle("Chart two");

            panel.add(new ColumnChart(newData, options_new));
```

I checked the generated html with firebug. The charts are rendered using SVG and in the second chart there are just no svg-tags for the labels, while they exist in the first chart. So the missing labels are not cut off or hidden, but are not even created.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this all your code? I can only see you drawing a single chart there. If you switch the order of the drawing of the two charts (draw chart 2 first), do the labels still show up on chart 1? If so, it's likely an issue with the code creating chart 1. If you switch the data tables, still same issue? You are the only one who can debug this currently.

Comment: @jmac There are definitely two charts in the code. If i switch the order, always the first chart has labels and all others don't. I also switched the data tables. Same issue. Always the first chart has labels and the second doesn't. Why do you think the issue is in creating the first chart. Do you think it somehow affects the others? I didn't see a chance to provide an SSCCE of a GWT project, that's why I provided the code above, which should be really easy to copy/paste into an existing gwt project. But if I can provide a better example, please let me know how. Thanks.

Comment: Try to re-create the same charts in the [google visualization playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#column_chart). If it happens there it might be a bug in google's chart library. Also use the [unofficial gwt wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/) instead of the official one. The official one is outdated and not maintained.

Comment: @Ümit using the unofficial gwt wrapper didn't help. Anyway thanks for the info. In the playground it works just fine.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, you're right, there are two charts. If it works in the playground but not in gwt, perhaps you are loading the wrong version of the library or somesuch?